# Populating a View based on a HttpPost returned parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is the foundation as far as application: ASP.Net, VS 2015, MVC, C#
My program has a SearchController with two actions:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    SearchModels displayView = new SearchModels();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string PurchaseOrder, DateTime PurchaseOrderDate)
{
    var dbSelect = from var in db.tblLectOrders
    where var.txtLectPurchaseOrder == PurchaseOrder
    where var.dteLectPurchaseOrderDate == PurchaseOrderDate
    select var;
    return View(dbSelect.ToList());
}
```

Seeing that the view that I used to load the page is called Search and the HttpPost is going to find a view  called Search to display the result, how can I accomplish that? I'm getting an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[LectOrderStatus.Models.tblLectOrder]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'LectOrderStatus.Models.SearchModel'.

I searched high and low for days to figure out this error. I can't seem to wrap my body around is and need some pointers in the right direction. First, I don't know which view it's trying to use, because as stated above the Search view is being used to display the page that asks for two pieces of information in order to perform the search. Then I would like to display the retrieved item(s) on a page in a grid view/table format. Do I use partial page? A complete new page? Thanks in advance in giving your assistance and expertise.

Comment: The message is self explanatory. Your view has `@model SearchModel`but your returning a model which is `List<tblLectOrder>` - they need to be the same

Comment: Add a property `List<tblLectOrder>` to your `SearchModels` and in the POST method, initialize it, and assign the value of `dbSelect` to it (along with the values of `PurchaseOrder` and `PurchaseOrderDate`)